# I ran clang-format on a makefile by mistake. How to undo?

Tags: makefile, clang-format

I have run `clang-format` on a `make` file by mistake. How to undo this clang-formatting?

Comment: Restore from source control.

Comment: ok thank you @DaveNewton

Comment: Did you do this while inside an editor? Then look for the "undo" function of your editor. If you don't have a backup, reformat manually and learn to use a source control system such as mercurial, git, or even RCS for single files.

Answer (score 0):

There is no functionality in `clang-format` for undoing a format operation.